# DOS:remove spaces

Tags: dos, spaces

I am executing the below script, but it is not working as there are spaces in between. Below is the script:

move C:\abc\d\System Table\Table Six (Top)\LogFiles*.jpg D:\Archive\

How can we eliminate the spaces in between & make sure the system understands so that it moved all jpg files to D:\Archive

Regards,
Orbit

Answer (score 5):

Place quotes around the file names.  That indications to the command line parser that everything between the quotes is a single token

```
move "C:\abc\d\System Table\Table Six (Top)\LogFiles*.jpg" "D:\Archive\"
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap long filenames in double quotes.

```
move "C:\abc\d\System Table\Table Six (Top)\LogFiles*.jpg" "D:\Archive\"
```

Answer (score 1):

For more DOS batch file commands and syntax, http://www.dostips.com/ has a pretty good list and lots of examples.

As an alternative, you could use the 8.3 representation and remove the spaces (though I prefer the quotes and spaces).

```
move C:\abc\d\System Table\Table Six (Top)\LogFiles*.jpg D:\Archive\

move C:\abc\d\System~1\Tables~1\LogFiles*.jpg D:\Archive\
```

If you have other similarly named directories, the `~?` could be different.